# how to include a file inside a model in codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2, codeigniter-url

I’m new to codeigniter and maybe my question is a bit stupid but..I cant understand how I can include a file inside a model.

Inside del model folder I’ve a subfolder named include and inside this I’ve some php file.

The structure is something like that:

-models

—mymodel.php

—include
—-file.php
—-file1.php

Inside mymodel.php how I can include the file.php?

I’ve heard that the relative path is allways the index.php, so I’ve tried:

```
 include ‘models/include/file.php’
```

but it seems not working.

I’ve tried to use base_url() and site_url() without any luck..

Can anyone help me?

Comment: maybe you should at first do `var_dump(__DIR__); exit;` instead of guessing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do:

```
base_url().'application/models/include/file.php'
```

(url helper must be loaded to use the base_url() function)

If you want a relative path:

```
./application/models/include/file.php
```

All files are relative to the main index.php, usually

Comment: @gaggina this is just how you could write the path to pass to include()

Comment: And this is not the right way to do it. I would recommend @Adhaata's answer

Answer (score 4):

Basically inserting direct file in model in not good approach. There are two best approach to follow... if you have class file then put your  file in application/library folder and from model call like this..

```
$this->load->library('file name without .php');
```

Then use methods similar as you include file

```
include(classname.php);
```

If this situation does not suits you then make a file in helper ...make functions and then call from anywhere controller or model or view...

Hope this will help