# Codeigniter include not working?

Tags: php, codeigniter, authentication

I have a feeling there is a really obvious solution to this but I'm just not seeing it. I'm building a website with codeigniter.

In my views directory I have two folders: `template` & `auth`.

I'm trying to include the header from the `template` directory into a php file in the `auth` directory.

I'm including it at the top, as always with `include '../template/header.php;'`

But I'm getting the error:

> Message: include(../template/header.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory
>
> Filename: auth/login.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To include any file in `CodeIgniter` you should do this :

```
$this->load->view('template/header');
```

You can read more about including file in `CodeIgniter` here :

[how to include a file inside a model in codeigniter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8228141/how-to-include-a-file-inside-a-model-in-codeigniter)

Comment: Fair does, but why not simply include the header from the view?

Comment: @styke, why not use the framework the way it was intended to be used?

Comment: @Mischa I have no problem with that, it's just I don't feel comfortable editing the auth controller's code and adding my template like this... it seems messy. I'm still going ahead with it.

Comment: @styke - Huh? Controller? You should add that in the view.

Comment: @Mischa As far as I know you can't call the function from the view...? I'm trying it now and it doesn't work.

Comment: @styke - You *can* call it in the view. I do it all the time. How are you trying to call it and what error do you get?

Comment: @Mischa my bad, had a massive brain-fart. Thanks for your help, I'll be using this method from now on.

Comment: Any time you use `include()`, `require()` or similar in CodeIgniter, the current working directory will be wherever the `index.php` file is, since that is where the request currently is. Your relative path was incorrect because of that. Similarly, CI has very useful constants such as `APPPATH`, and `VIEWPATH` in 3.0, for specifying certain directories.